# Swagger with Programmatic REST API(Jersey)

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

I tried searching for quite sometime and couldn't find the solution thus posting this question.

I have a Java Web project where we generate REST APIs programmatically(ie WITHOUT Jersey annotations like @Path/@Get etc) based on files(proprietary xml) provided by another tool which is kind of a standard in my organization through Jersey(ResourceConfig eg https://docs.huihoo.com/jersey/2.13/resource-builder.html) and we have a need of generating its corresponding SWAGGER docs.
All the tutorials that I found were using declarative API including page eg. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5

I also looked into Swagger-Inflector which makes use of swagger.yaml file but in my case we need to generate it runtime with no manual work.

This is how(similar sample) we generate REST api:

```
final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder();
resourceBuilder.path("helloworld");
final ResourceMethod.Builder methodBuilder = resourceBuilder.addMethod("GET");
methodBuilder.produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
             .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>() {
             @Override
             public String apply(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
                    return "Hello World!";
             }
         });
final Resource resource = resourceBuilder.build();
registerResources(resource);
```

Is this feasible? Can we generate Swagger docs for programmatically generated REST APIs?